# Prometheus Query with sum by(status) Producing No Results in Combined Query Despite Individual Queries Working

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with a Prometheus query where combining two queries results in no data, even though each individual query returns results. The goal is to calculate the difference in the number of tasks with different statuses over a 1-hour period. Here's the combined query:

```
sum by(status) (increase(number_of_tasks_total{queue=~"$queuename", kubernetes_namespace=~"$namespace", status="unique"}[1h])) - on(status) sum by(status) (increase(number_of_tasks_total{queue=~"$queuename", kubernetes_namespace=~"$namespace", status="enqueued"}[1h]))
```

The expectation is that after sum by(status), the only remaining label should be status, thus allowing the subtraction operation to work correctly. However, I'm getting no results with this combined query.

Key Points:

Each individual query part works fine and returns data.
The issue seems related to label mismatching after sum by(status), but I'm not sure why this is happening since status should be the only label remaining after the aggregation.
Variables `$queuename` and `$namespace` are used in the query, and they seem to be functioning as expected.

Questions:

Why is there a label mismatch when the sum by(status) should ensure only the status label is present?
Are there any hidden labels or implicit behaviors in Prometheus that might cause this unexpected result?
Could the increase function be affecting the labels in a way that's not immediately obvious?
Any insights or suggestions on how to debug this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Problem of your query is in mismatching label status of the operands: LHS produces `status="unique"` and RHS - `status="enqueued"`.

When you write `on(status)` you instruct Prometheus to match operands using only labels in the list (ignoring all others), but this match is done by exact equality of label values.

So in your query `on()` should be used instead.